# Meteor MongoDB return single object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
{
    "_id" : "R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR",
    "practiceSetup" : {
        "operatoriesSettings" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Operatory 1",
                "description" : "Room 1",
                "status" : true
            },
                            {
                "name" : "Operatory 2",
                "description" : "Room B",
                "status" : true
            }
        ],  

}
```

I'm trying to lookup object that has name "Operatory 1" and only return that object.

Here is what I have tried,

```
Practice.findOne({ _id: 'R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR' }, { "$elemMatch": { "practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings": { "name": "Operatory 1" } } } );
```

However this will return the whole document, not that particular object, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I think I just answered a very similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624171/getting-subdocument-from-document/47624861#47624861

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this,

```
Practice.findOne({ _id: 'R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR' }).map(function(u){
        return u.practiceSetup
                .operatoriesSettings
                .filter( m => m.name == "Operatory 1");
    })
```

This will return:

```
[
 [ 
    {
        "name" : "Operatory 1",
        "description" : "Room 1",
        "status" : true
    }
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) projection works:

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

If you only need that specific subdocument, you get it using JS:

```js
const doc = Practice.findOne(
  { _id: 'R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR' },
  {
    $elemMatch: {
      'practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings': {
        name: 'Operatory 1'
      }
    }
  }
);

const operator1 = doc.practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using "Projections" will return matched object off an array.

Query:

```
{ "_id": "R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR", "practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings": { $elemMatch: {'name': 'Operatory 1'} } }
```

Projection

```
{"practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings.$.name": 1}
```

Full Query:

```
db.Practice.findOne({ 
    "_id" : "R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR", 
    "practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings" : {
        "$elemMatch" : {
            "name" : "Operatory 1"
        }
    }
}, { 
    "practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings.$.name" : 1.0
});
```

Returns

```
{ 
    "_id" : "R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR", 
    "practiceSetup" : {
        "operatoriesSettings" : [
            {
                "name" : "Operatory 1", 
                "description" : "Room 1", 
                "status" : true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Meteor**

When using Meteor methods, you will need to use "[fields](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/mongodb-queries-and-projections)" when using Projections.

```
   return Practice.findOne({
        "_id": "R9zbu8oTWwgxT5eCR",
        "practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "name": data
          }
        }
      }, 
        { fields: { 'practiceSetup.operatoriesSettings.$.name': 1, _id: 0 } }
       );
```